# ArcGIS raster to vector with shapefile feed procedure

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygonize

Does a procedure like Polygonize raster to vector exist in ArcGIS that can do the following?

I have a raster image, a shapefile (.shp) with all the regions of interest and I need a vector output with those polygons only.

Comment: If you have a shapefile with the regions of interest don't you already have vector polygons?

Comment: There may be a way to have the polygons you input along with the rest that will be constructed.

Comment: Are you trying to extract polygon features from an image but only within the polygons of the shapefile?  If so, what tool have you used to perform the feature extraction without those constraining polygons?

Comment: I had conducted classification processes @PolyGeo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from rasters to polygons go to ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> from raster -> Raster to polygon.

The raster must be an integer type. ie the values in each cell must be 1,2,3 not 1.1, 3.1415926 etc

After you have your polygons from the raster images and tidied them up (error check them as well) do a spatial clip using the second polygon layer so you only have polygons inside (or touching depending on what you want) the area of interest.

Comment: It also helps if you can convert your rasters to black and white or gray scale first

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Banger, it is quite fine, could you please be more specific as to how to tidy the raster images ?

Comment: Sorry ODstuck, I was referring to the polygons created by the conversion from raster to vector.  It might be worth asking this as a separate question as I think the GIS SE have a 1 question per post rule.

Comment: Yes, @Banger i was referring to the polygons as well :)  Thank you for the assistance!